# C# Using Async and Await, Wrong Return Type

Tags: c#

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task buttonPaste_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxVideoLink.Text = Clipboard.GetText(System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.Text);

    string uri = textBoxVideoLink.Text;
    var youTube = YouTube.Default;
    var video = await youTube.GetVideoAsync(uri);

    textBoxVideoTitle.Text = video.Title;
}
```

There are no visible errors and it builds but then I get an error in `FormMain.Designer.cs` and it underscores (`this.buttonPaste_ClickAsync`);

The actual error is `Task FormMain.buttonPaste_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)` has the wrong return type.

Comment: Why do you want to return Task? You can make this method `void`

Comment: Yes, button click events have to be async void. No getting around it. :(

Comment: When I used the WAIT command it underscored an error with youTube.GetVideoAsync(uri);. SO I highlighted the error and VS recommended the Task part. Daniel, so I can't have this code in an button click? I'll try it elsewhere.

Comment: @Siggy you can, just understand that it will be a "async void" and be aware of [the potential issues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Scott I put void after async and got rid of the System.Threading.Tasks.Task. Now everything is fine. Thank you! I'd vote for you but I don't know if I can.

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same issue today where I had a button that was posting some data to an API and I had to do it `asynchronously` to avoid any issues on the User Interface. But it wasn't allowing the method signature to be `async Task` so what worked for me was simple, I just replace `async Task` with `async void`. For example, I modified it to look like below:

```
public async void btn1_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
{
     // await your API call.
}
```

**PS:** In case you want to read and interact with the User interface object like displaying text in labels or setting text to textboxes, you might want to Invoke the control so it doesn't throw any thread exceptions as it might not allow you to interact with the UI thread in an `async method`